# django rest framework: change in ListAPIView return format?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Just in the process of upgrading django rest framework from 3.2.3 to 3.4.6.
I also upgraded django from 1.8.6 to 1.10

It looks like return values from ListAPIView have changed format? i.e. they used to be objects like

```
{
  "count": 0,
  "next": null,
  "previous": null,
  "results": []
}
```

but now are just straight arrays?

```
[]
```

I'm looking all over the place trying to find documentation for this change but can't find any. Is anyone able to help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently now in django rest framework you must explictly set the pagination class or at least a global default.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#setting-the-pagination-style